# fabric-ca authentication can it be done with the help of CLI commands

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I do want to know how the authentication can be done for users in the fabric ca and how to validate the users registered. Can it be authenticated by writing CLI commands and thereby invoking the shell scripts or it can be only web application .

I have referred the documents in the official site.
https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with any of the 2 ways

1. using the **fabric-ca-client binary**.Here you would be using the
   commands to register and enroll admins,peers,client,orderer,ca and
   create their identity.
2. using the the **sdk** where there is a node module called
   fabric-ca-client. eg:view the enrollAdmin and registerUser in fabcar
   example [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/fabcar/javascript).

if still confused do comment.

Comment: Hey Hi, Thanks for the response . I do wanted to do in java(sdk) and im just the beginner i doesnt know where to start with . My task is to authenticate and validate the users .

Comment: https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk/blob/master/java/src/main/java/org/example/client/CAClient.java  hope this helps you with your task.If it dint then do revert.

Answer (score 0):

Run the network and type `docker ps`. Note the name of the CA you wish to use. Once that is done the below two commands will give you what you are looking for.

`fabric-ca-client certificates list` and `fabric-ca-client certificates -id "ENTER_USERNAME"`

You may either execute them in the CLI container (image of fabric-tools) or directly on the ca container using
`docker exec -t ca.org1.example.com fabric-ca-client certificates list`. To get additional commands run `docker exec -t ca.org1.example.com fabric-ca-client --help`.

You can find additional documentation [using this link](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#manage-certificates). Note since these are bash scripts, it doesnt matter which SDK or chaincode language you use.